# Is there a way to disable the <a> link preview in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever you hover over a link it shows the thingy with the link in it at the bottom left of the web browser, How would you disable this?. I am hoping to use as little javascript as possible, but if I have to use it that's fine.

Here is the css I currently have for my navbar buttons. *if needed*.

```css
.navbar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 166, 0);
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
}
```

I would like to have it not show up, just to make the website look a little bit cleaner.

Comment: Could you use something other than a <a> tag? You could use a button and style it, but you'll have to use some javascript to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Don't bother. People like me like to see where links are going to ensure we're not being taken to spam/malicious sites. Concealing that information (even it was possible which I doubt it is) just makes you look sinister. I doubt that even the user (who has control of the browser) can do this.

Comment: This is a security feature. Disabling security features because they don't look pretty is not a great idea.

Comment: I screwed around with it a bit to make sure, but I don't think it is possible with only css hacks(I had a couple ideas that I thought might work in a longshot). The only way I know of to get it to be hidden is to not use the href attribute, use css to make it look like a link with an href, and then add a click handler that does the navigation. But there are also accessibility things to think about if you do that.

Comment: A long time ago there was a way to do this easily via javascript, then it was realized that malicious links were being masked, so for security reasons it was removed (possibly last century)

Comment: You can move the destination into another attribute. Then write a click event listener that copies that attribute into `href`.

Comment: Refer to this question to help resolve this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605481/css-html-disable-link-hover-text

Comment: Yes you can do (using JS) it but please don't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS/HTML: Disable link "hover" text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605481/css-html-disable-link-hover-text)

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this is to remove the data in 'href', and change it to a javascript onlick where you set the window.location to the url you want.

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Go To SO</a>
```

becomes

```
<a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="javascript: window.location = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/';">Go To SO</a>
```

p.s. Doing it via JavaScript is probably the only way to disable the URL display, but this raises the question of why? URL display is a valid and important thing, and disabling it is not good for user experience.

Comment: One of the reason to disable preview is to prevent inaccurate of analytics...